# How do I declare a static block in magento?

Tags: magento

I put a file in the following location phtml

```
page/html/black-friday.phtml
```

I created a static block in magento and I put the following code

```
{{block type="core/template" template="black-friday.phtml"}}
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with the above code?
The problem is that does not recognize the block ..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the full .phtml address for your block relative to your design path. like if your design pack is `prettypack` then the path would be `page/html/black-friday.phtml` which is located inside `design/prettypack/template/page/html/black-friday.phtml`

Comment: {{block type="core/template" template="page/html/black-friday.phtml"}}  so we need? I put and still not working

Comment: block works ... if you put something in it then displays